How have these linear functionals for boundary conditions been formulated?
I am reading a book on Green's function to solve PDEs and I am stuck at a text in the book.
To start with we have a $n^{th}$-order linear ODE  with the linear operator $\textbf{L}$. The text says and I quote as follows:

Since $\textbf{L}$ is of $n$-th order, there will be $n$ such conditions of the general form:
$$ \mathbf{B_j}(u) = c_j; j = 1,2,..n $$ where the $c_j$'s are given constants, and the $\mathbf{B}_j's$ are prescribed functionals of the unknown $u$. More specifically, we will limit our attention throughout to $\mathbf{B}_j$'s which are linear combinations of $u$ and it's derivatives, through order $n-1$, at the two endpoints $a$, $b$.

This I understand.
Continuing with the text in the book:

For $n=2$, for example, we have
$$ 
\mathbf{B}_1(u) = a_{10}u(a) + a_{11}u'(a) + b_{10}u(b) + b_{11}u'(b) = c_1
$$
$$
\mathbf{B}_2(u) = a_{20}u(a) + a_{21}u'(a) + b_{20}u(b) + b_{21}u'(b) = c_2
$$

I am unable to understand how these two equations have been formulated.
I was expecting the equations to be of the form:
$$ 
\mathbf{B}_1(u) = a_{10}u(a) + a_{11}u'(a) = c_1
$$
$$
\mathbf{B}_2(u) = a_{20}u(b) + a_{21}u'(b) = c_2
$$
Can someone please point out what I am missing in my understanding ?
